# The best way to create strings file in Java server like String.xml in Android

Tags: java

I want to create file `String.xml`. What is the best way to do this?

In my server I have some `Strings` that I want to set them from some file (like `String.xml`), because I need to support languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're writing a plain Java EE application, you can take a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaxv.html).

If you are using a framework, nearly everyone of them include an internalization (i18n) plugin that allows you to define languages.